# Why is my R code not getting past first iteration

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I am trying to get loop top get past `i=1` but with no luck.

Can someone please help. Thank you.

```
mixed_acc<- tan_acc <- exp_acc <- gau_acc <- list()
for (i in 1:3){
  load(paste0("run", i, ".rData"))
  mixed_acc[[i]] <- Model_eval_Mixed[[1]]$Specs1
  tan_acc[[i]] <- Model_eval_Tan[[1]]$Specs1
  exp_acc[[i]] <- Model_eval_Exp[[1]]$Specs1
  gau_acc[[i]] <- Model_eval_Gau[[1]]$Specs1
}
```

Comment: it is a bit difficult to answer without more details. does it stop at the first iteration because of an error? if yes, can you mention it?

Comment: There is no error. When printing i at the end of the loop, it does not get past 1.

Comment: If i write i = 1, i = 2, ... separately in the loop, then it works

Comment: maybe try to print i inside the loop to see what's going on (to know if you run the loop several times but without changes of i, or if it runs only one time). by adding print(i) at the last line of the loop

Comment: printing i results in i = 1 being printed three times.

Comment: this is strange. if you run this piece of code: l = list()
for (i in 1:3){
  l[[i]] = i
  print(i)
}
i takes the values 1,2 and 3 right? Maybe the dataset you are loading contains a i value which is erasing the one from the loop? (I'd be surprise though)

Comment: Is this correct: `Model_eval_Mixed[[1]]$Specs1`?  There is a one in the "[[ ]]" so all of the list items will be equal.

Comment: Yes, this is correct as they are from different .rData files. I am trying to use the append() function which sort of gets me there, but there are now lots of lists within a list.

Comment: per glagla comment, try replacing the first line of the loop with `if("i" %in% load(paste0("run", i, ".rData"))) stop("Houston, we have a problem.")`